# How Can I Add Clickable Buttons at the End of Each TextView?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, navigation

I'm making an application which displays contacts and their details such as phone number, email etc. and displays them in a ListView. I want to add clickable buttons at the end of each row so that e.g. I can click the button next to phone number and open the string stored in the TextView in dialler, how can I do this? My .xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please elaborate! What have you done so far? You need to implement custom list view in order to achieve this!

Comment: I have an adapter class which extends BaseAdapter and a class with constructors to store data in the TextView's. I also have a display list class which implements ListView to display the data stored in the directory. The directory displays fine, I just want to add functionality so that when I click on a button inside e.g. phone or email TextView, it opens in dialler/email etc.

Comment: My suggestion: Instead of Button's click, use onclick for textview. When clicked on list row just. Using the position get the phone number and use it as URI by passing it to ACTION_DIAL parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, at the moment, all the TextView's and Avatar which make up a contact are highlighted when touched, as if they are merged like a group, how I would go about being able to individually select a part of a contact such as the phone or email etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/yourClickableImage"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/yourClickableImage"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/yourClickableImage"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/yourClickableImage"/>

</LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/yourClickableImage"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/yourClickableImage"/>

</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"`enter code here`
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLoation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/yourClickableImage"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/yourClickableImage"/>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know is this the way you want ? Tell me and I will edit it for you :).

Comment: Hi, the code you've provided isn't showing a lot of syntax errors unfortunately.

Comment: Try now I have done some changes. It should work else give me errors.

Answer (score 3):

xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
//add button where you want and type the code: android:onClick="functionName"


    </LinearLayout>
```

Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       public void functionName(View view){
//set of codes you want to perform

}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

u can define the clickable function of your button in your java file!

add code in your xml file:-

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bun"
        android:text="click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bun);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//set codes u want to perform
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I would like the button aligned to the right inside of the TextView fields if possible, how can I do that?

Comment: look out my new answer below aligning the button to the right!

Answer (score 3):

here it is your xml file which shows button on the right side of your textview
as you wanted! :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdffgh"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdffgh" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdffgh" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdffgh" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="click" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```